# tournament $G=(V,E)$ property

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a tournament

For the definition of a tournament see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory))

> Prove: There exists a vertex $v \in V$ such that there exists a path of length $\le2$ to every other vertex $w \in V$

Suppose that this is not true, then every vertex $v \in V$ has a vertex $w \in V$ it can only reach with more than $2$ edges.

I don't see how this would contradict tournament-property.

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Can you state more clearly on what "being reached with edges" means? Do you mean edge-disjoint paths? And I suggest you to revise the definition of tournament, for example, with which in wikipedia.

Comment: @Salomo I edited the question. By "reached by" I mean there exists a directed path of length $\le 2$ to any other vertex

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the vertices *players*; let's say that player $v$ *beats* player $w$ if there's an arc from $v$ to $w;$ and let's define the *score* (or *outdegree*) of player $v$ to be the number of players that $v$ beats.

**Claim.** If $v$ is any player with the maximum score, then there is a path of length $2$ from $v$ to any other player.

**Proof.** Let $w$ be any other player. If $w$ beats $v,$ and also beats everyone that $v$ beats, then $w$ has a greater score than $v,$ contradicting the assumption that $v$ has the maximum score. Therefore, either $w$ is beaten by $v$ (so there is a path of length $1$ from $v$ to $w$), or else $w$ is beaten by some player who is beaten by $v$ (so there is a path of length $2$ from $v$ to $w$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $d(v,u)$ be the distance from $v$ to $u,$ and let $$N(v)=|\{u\in V|d(v,u)\le2\}|$$  Let $v$ be a vertex such that $N(v)$ is maximal.  If $N(v)=|V|$ we are done.  Otherwise, there is a vertex $w\in V$ such that $d(v,w)>2$.  If for some vertex $u$ there is an arc $vu,$ then there cannot be an arc $uw,$ for then there would be a path of length $2$ from $v$ to $w$.  Since the graph is a tournament, there is an edge $wu,$ and so $u\ne 
 v\implies d(w,u)\le d(v, u)$.  That is, $N(w)\ge N(v)$.  However,  $d(v,w)>1\implies d(w,v)=1$ and $$N(w)>N(v),$$
contradicting the definition of $v$.